# Project API - duration field not showing the same value as Web app

Tags: clockify

Project API - [https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/[Token]/projects?archived=false&page-size=1000](https://api.clockify.me/api/v1/workspaces/%5BToken%5D/projects?archived=false&page-size=1000)

"duration": "PT??H" is not inline with the value on the web app.

Appreciate any guidance - I am using the API to get the total hour logged against a project for some calculation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you'll have to extract the duration as the data is uniquely formatted via the API.

IE. PT25H20M12S is 25 hours, 20min and 12 seconds.

Every time format seems to be prefixed with PT so everything after is the actual time entry.